# pattern when using Math.random

Tags: java, random

I am trying to have a mouse go through rooms to a target room. I am using a graph-like system with an x and y axis. I have a problem where the computer doesn't seem to want to add or subtract from an already existing variable.

Console:

```
The mouse is in room (5,4) 
The mouse is in room (5,6) 
The mouse is in room (6,5) 
The mouse is in room (5,4) 
The mouse is in room (5,6) 
The mouse is in room (5,6)
```

Code for mouse:

```
package mouse_maze;

public class Mouse {

    private int xCord = 5;
    private int yCord = 5;
    //position of the mouse when it starts


    public int getXCord() {
        return this.xCord;
    }
    public int getYCord() {
        return this.yCord;
    }

    public void move() {
    //method for the movement of the mouse
        boolean verticalMove = Math.random() < .5;
        boolean horizontalMove;
        if (verticalMove == true)
            horizontalMove = false;
        else
            horizontalMove = true;
        int moveBy = 1;
        if (Math.random() < .5)
            moveBy = -1;
        if (verticalMove) {
            int test = this.yCord + moveBy;
            if(test < 1 || test > 9) return;
            this.yCord += moveBy;
        }
        if (horizontalMove) {
            int test = this.xCord + moveBy;
            if(test < 1 || test > 9) return;
            this.xCord += moveBy;
        }
        System.out.println("The mouse is in room (" + xCord + "," + yCord + ")");
    }
}
```

Code for maze:

```
package mouse_maze;

public class Maze {

    private boolean onGoing = false;
    private int tarX;
    private int tarY;
    //creates the target for the mouse.

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Maze(6, 8).init();
    }
    public Maze(int tarX, int tarY) {
        this.tarX = tarX;
        this.tarY = tarY;
    }
    public void init() {
        this.onGoing = true;
        while(this.onGoing)
            this.iterate();
    }
    public void iterate() {
        Mouse m = new Mouse();
        m.move();
        if (m.getXCord() == tarX && m.getYCord() == tarY) {
            this.onGoing = false;
            System.out.println("The mouse has beat the maze!");
            //checks if the mouse has gotten to the target room.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Er, how does your title relate to your question?

Comment: -1 for unrelated title, unrelated tag, bad code formatting, and unclear question

Comment: I'm saying that there is a problem with the random not being very random.

Comment: -1 for not explaining your code well, or your expected behavior. Please -- we don't read minds well.

Comment: @RishavBasu Prove it. If it is the randomness of Java Random you are in concern, you can easily demonstrate by having a little program to show how you get the random number, and shows there is actually a "pattern"

Comment: You should look at your `iterate` method again. Follow the logic through. The program is just doing what it's programmed to do.

Comment: As a side note, just do `boolean horizontalMove = !verticalMove;` No need for the if/else blocks there. And there's never a need for `if (foo == true)`. You would just do `if (foo)`.

Comment: and, in your question body, you described your problem as: "I have a problem where the computer doesn't seem to want to add or subtract from an already existing variable."  How is it supposed to be related to randomness?

Answer (score 3):

First, learn to use a debugger, or at least learn to debug by whatever means.  It is meaningless to always "assume" the problem without actually proving it.

Your whole problem has nothing to do with random etc.

In your `iterate()` method, you are creating a new mouse every time, instead of having the same mouse keep on moving.